# python assigning variable value to message payload body

Tags: python

I am learning python and i want to know how to assign the variable to json.

```
a=10
b=11

body='{
"mode":"async", 
"messageType":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
"messages":[{"Temperature":"", #----------->assign a value 10 
              "Humidity":"",   #----------->assign b value 11 here
              "timestamp":1468991773}]
}'



body=('{"mode":"async", "messageType":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "messages":[{"Temperature":"", "Humidity":"", "timestamp":1468991773}]}'
```

I need to assign those 2 variables to messages part of the http body.

Thanks.

Comment: " assign those 2 variables to messages part of the http body"? unclear. Do you want to create a json string containing the same thing but with a and b values instead of the empty fields?

Comment: Put them in there the same way you would put values into any other string. Or better yet, build a Python data structure rather than a JSON string and then convert it to JSON using `json.dump`

Comment: google `python string formating`

Comment: Have you I dunno, tried reading some docs? This question is incredibly vague.